# Get absolute paths of all files in a directory

Tags: python, absolute-path

How do I get the absolute paths of all the files in a directory that could have many sub-folders in Python?

I know `os.walk()` recursively gives me a list of directories and files, but that doesn't seem to get me what I want.

Comment: Could you give an example of what input and output you expect

Answer (score 111, accepted):

[`os.path.abspath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) makes sure a path is absolute. Use the following helper function:

```
import os

def absoluteFilePaths(directory):
    for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
```

Comment: I think it is nicer to do the abspath just once, on the `os.walk` line, than to do it N times inside the loop

Comment: That works, but only by "accident". Reading `os.path.join`'s contract, I cannot find any place that guarantees that the result is absolute if one of the arguments is, although that's a sensible assumption.

Comment: @phihag  That's reliable. It is not "accident", and the language is not so formal as to have any notion of "contracts" in the docs. It's documented that *if a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.* Python cannot invisibly transform into a relative path here, and it would be impossible to modify the behavior without a huge backwards breaking change. If still not convinced, you can even just read the source of `os.path.join`, which is short and simple.

Answer (score 38):

If the argument given to [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is absolute, then the root dir names yielded during iteration will also be absolute. So, you only need to join them with the filenames:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath("../path/to/dir/")):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean, just I didn't want the files, but wanted specific subdirs. I've posted the solution below.

Answer (score 35):

You can use stdlib [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) (or the [backport](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/) if you have Python version < 3.4):

```
import pathlib
for filepath in pathlib.Path(directory).glob('**/*'):
    print(filepath.absolute())
```

Comment: This is very nice that it uses python 3, but it also shows directories.

Comment: @Newskooler, one can use `iterdir` again from [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir)

Answer (score 12):

Starting with python 3.5 the idiomatic solution would be:

```
import os

def absolute_file_paths(directory):
    path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    return [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(path) if entry.is_file()]
```

This not just reads nicer but also is faster in many cases.
For more details (like ignoring symlinks) see original python docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir

Comment: scandir() is not recursive

Comment: And `os.walk` uses scandir when available anyway  [(ref)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/#os-walk)

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        p=os.path.join(root,file)
        print p
        print os.path.abspath(p)
        print
```

Comment: Anyway to do this without capturing hidden files?

Comment: @MarcelMarino `if not file.startswith('.')`

Answer (score 9):

You can use `os.path.abspath()` to turn relative paths into absolute paths:

```
file_paths = []

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  for filename in files:
    file_paths.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename)))
```

Comment: doesn't this join the `cwd` to `filename`, when you want to join the `folder`?!

Comment: simplified to one line:
`root_path="<your root path>"`
`file_paths = [path`
`for folder, subs, files in os.walk(root_path)`
`for filename in files`
`for path in os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename))]`

Answer (score 5):

All files and folders:

```py
x = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, p)) for p in os.listdir(directory)]
```

Images (.jpg | .png):

```py
x = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, p)) for p in os.listdir(directory) if p.endswith(('jpg', 'png'))]
```

Comment: how do you make sure it's only files not directories in this oneliner?

Answer (score 3):

```py
from glob import glob


def absolute_file_paths(directory):
    return glob(join(directory, "**"))
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question you still might consider adding a few explanatory sentences as this increases the value of your answer for other users.

Comment: This only works when you also import `join` from the `os` module, like so: `from os.path import join`. Doesn't do folders recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = 'Desktop'
files = filter(lambda filepath: filepath.is_file(), Path(path).glob('*'))
for file in files:
   print(file.absolute())
```

Comment: Your import statement imports `Path` directly, but then you call `pathlib.Path()` in the code. Currently doesn't run unless you fix that. Otherwise nice and clean solution @Pygirl.

Comment: In this example, there is no need to make `list` out of those files, filter returns a generator.

Comment: @MaLiN2223: Yeah it's true but I want to store the file list because when the generator is exhaust then files will give none. Anyway I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(directory):
 for directory in directories:
         print os.path.join(root, directory)
 for filename in filenames:
     if filename.endswith(".JPG"):
        print filename
        print os.path.join(root,filename)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
pth=''
types=os.listdir(pth)
for type_ in types:
     file_names=os.listdir(f'{pth}/{type_}')
     file_names=list(map(lambda x:f'{pth}/{type_}/{x}',file_names))
     train_folder+=file_names
```