# list all files in directory under different user python

Tags: python, path

I need to list absolute paths to files in a directory for python `3.7.5`. Now the issue is that neither of the solutions specified here work:

[Get absolute paths of all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816816/get-absolute-paths-of-all-files-in-a-directory)

Perhaps because I log in to a different user and my home directory changes: `sudo su - my_user_name`

Such solutions:

```
files = [Path(x).absolute() for x in os.listdir(source_folder)]
```

or

```
files = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir(source_folder)]
```

Result in appending current working dir to the correctly found names of the files. So, if I list directory: `/other_home/data/gene_data` (which has a file named `my_file.tsv`), but I am in some `/new_home/def/cram/my_project_name`, The above solutions produce the path: `/new_home/def/cram/my_project_name/my_file.tsv` and not `/other_home/data/gene_data/my_file.tsv`. Is there a way still to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the filename without path, which makes it a relative path based on `source_folder`. `os.path.abspath` doesn't know about `source_folder`. All it knows about is the current working directory. So, it assumes CWD is the relative path that you want to be made absolute.

You could join the known path component before making it absolute

```
files = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_folder, x)) 
            for x in os.listdir(source_folder)]
```

When using `Path` you have a similar problem. You created the path from the filename which lacks its path component, so `Path` assumes you meant the current working directory. Instead have `Path` do the directory enumeration for you so that it passes back properly qualified `Path` objects.

```
files = [x.absolute() for x in Path(source_folder).glob("*")]
```