# How to copy files from folder or subfolder with Python?

Tags: python, shutil

I have a Folder with many subfolders that also have subfolder in them and they also have subfolders and so on. I need certain files from that folder to be found by python and copied to a destination folder.

I found shutil.copy but this need the complete path to find the file.

How do i copy files with Python that are either in the folder or one of the subfolders or their subfolders... ?

Edit: I dont have the complete Path to the files, the files are somewhere in that folder structre, if i would have the complete path this wouldnt be a problem.

Comment: use `pathlib.Path.glob` with some filters and use copy on them ?

Comment: "...but this need the complete path". So, provide the complete path. What's the problem?

Comment: Check if your target directory is empty and then use loop if not. Use recursion.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki the problem is that i dont know the complete Path. Thats why i need it to search through. The FIles are somewhere in this giant folder structure

Comment: @MateuszStyrna here is the problem that i dont know how deep the folders go and that not every searched file has to exist somewhere in the structure

Answer (score 0):

Before copy using shutil.copy,
get absolute path of all files

```
import os

def absoluteFilePaths(directory):
    for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for f in filenames:
            yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
```

[Get absolute paths of all files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816816/get-absolute-paths-of-all-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: Here is the Problem again that i dont know the complete Path the files are somewhere in this big folder structure. Meaning i dont have a source path

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-shutil-copytree-method/

The solutions seems to be `shutil.copytree()`

```
# Python program to explain shutil.copytree() method 
       
# importing os module 
import os 
   
# importing shutil module 
import shutil 
   
# path 
path = 'C:/Users / Rajnish / Desktop / GeeksforGeeks'
   
# List files and directories 
# in 'C:/Users / Rajnish / Desktop / GeeksforGeeks' 
print("Before copying file:") 
print(os.listdir(path)) 
   
   
# Source path 
src = 'C:/Users / Rajnish / Desktop / GeeksforGeeks / source'
   
# Destination path 
dest = 'C:/Users / Rajnish / Desktop / GeeksforGeeks / destination'
   
# Copy the content of 
# source to destination 
destination = shutil.copytree(src, dest) 
   
# List files and directories 
# in "C:/Users / Rajnish / Desktop / GeeksforGeeks" 
print("After copying file:") 
print(os.listdir(path)) 
   
# Print path of newly 
# created file 
print("Destination path:", destination)
```

Comment: This copies the complete folder tree, i only need some files that are somewhere in that tree